# how to sort bucket key to integer in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

i have a problem with sorting by bucket key.

how do i sort bucket key by integer?

this is my query.

```
{
"aggregations": {
    "by_time": {
        "terms": {
            "script": {
                "source": "Instant.ofEpochMilli(doc['statdate'].date.millis).atZone(ZoneId.of(params.tz)).hour",
                "lang": "painless",
                "params": {
                    "tz": "Asia/Seoul"
                }
            },
            "size": 10,
            "min_doc_count": 0,
            "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
            "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
            "order": {
                "_key": "asc"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and result.

```
{
"aggregations": {
    "sterms#by_time": {
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "11",
                "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
                "key": "19",
                "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
                "key": "22",
                "doc_count": 1
                }
            },
            {
                "key": "7",
                "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
                "key": "9",
                "doc_count": 7
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

but i don't want this result.

i think what this key type is string.

how can i sort by integer key?

Comment: can you please share your index data,mapping and expected search result ?

Comment: mapping ` "mappings": {
        "trend": {
            "properties": {
                "pfno": { "type": "keyword" },
                "statdate": { "type": "date" },

                "pageview": { "type": "long" }
            }
        }
}`

Comment: thanks for your reply  Can you please share your expected search result as well ?

Comment: i want result {
"aggregations": {
    "sterms#by_time": {
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "7",
                "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
                "key": "9",
                "doc_count": 7
            },
            {
                "key": "11",
                "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
                "key": "19",
                "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
                "key": "22",
                "doc_count": 1
                }
            }
            
        ]
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

> You need to use [bucket sort aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-sort-aggregation.html) that is a parent pipeline
> aggregation which sorts the buckets of its parent multi-bucket
> aggregation. Zero or more sort fields may be specified together with
> the corresponding sort order. Each bucket may be sorted based on its
> _key, _count or its sub-aggregations.

Try out this search query:

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "by_time": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": "Instant.ofEpochMilli(doc['statdate'].date.millis).atZone(ZoneId.of(params.tz)).hour",
          "lang": "painless",
          "params": {
            "tz": "Asia/Seoul"
          }
        },
        "size": 20,            <-- note this
        "min_doc_count": 0,
        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
        "order": {
          "_key": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "bucket_truncate": {
          "bucket_sort": {            <-- note this
            "sort": [
              {
                "_key": {
                  "order": "asc"
                }
              }
            ],
        "size": 20         <-- note this  
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "id":"1",
  "title":"a"
}
{
  "id":"3",
  "title":"c"
}
{
  "id":"2",
  "title":"b"
}
{
  "id":"2",
  "title":"c"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "unique_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "bucket_truncate": {
          "bucket_sort": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "_key": {
                  "order": "asc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "unique_id": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "1",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "2",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "3",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: thank you. but this query work only under "10". result key is [ "1", "2", "3", "4", ... "23", "24" ]

Comment: @khasui you can add a size param that indicates, the number of buckets to return. (Defaults to all buckets of the parent aggregation.) Please go through my updated answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue

Comment: @khasui since in your query of terms aggregation, you have explicitly mentioned the size as 10, you need to change that also 

Comment: i try. but this is not working too. can you add "10" or "11" key ?

Comment: {
  "aggr": {
    "by_time": {
      "terms": {
        ...
        "size": 20,
        ...
        "order": {
          "_key": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggr": {
        "sort": {
          "bucket_sort": {
              "sort": [
                {
                  "_key": {
                    "order": "asc"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "from": 0,
              "size": 20,
              "gap_policy": "SKIP"
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }
} i added aggregation size and terms size 20. it is wrong?